# LS command responds: garbage option

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do a script where I need to get a program process ID,

`$ var=$"ps -u pi | grep bot.py | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1"`

but instead of it I'm getting:

```
**error: user name does not exist**
Usage:

ps [options]
Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>
or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: No command is run using the code you show; did you mean `$(...)` instead of `$"..."`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this sort of problem, try each part of the pipeline in turn (so try the "ps -upi" command, then "ps -upi | grep bot.py" until you find the failing step.

I assume that "bot.py" is being run by the "pi" user, and you may be running this as another user ("ps -u" in the previous answer will return processes being run by the user running the command, in a prettified format).

Also, you should be enclosing the command in parentheses, not quotes, and you don't need a sequence of grep, awk, head etc, just use awk. You end up with

```
$ var=$(ps -u pi | awk '/bot\.py/{print $1; exit}')
```

Edit: I'd missed trailing parenthesis off, and the "." in bot.py will atch any characters - escape it to match a real dot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following updated script code:-

```
$ var=$"ps -u | grep bot.py | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1"
```

Here we have removed 'pi' argument from `ps -u pi` to `ps -u` command. and we are printing 2 element which is pid using `awk '{print $2}'`.

It will return the pid of process whose name contains script bot.py and assign it to var.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still getting the same result. I'm running this script on a raspberry pi